# What do 5 short beeps followed by a one second pause and a normal bios beep mean?

Tags: bios

**Motherboard:** ASRock Fatal1ty Z87 Killer

**Graphics card:** AMD HD 5850

**Processor:** Intel i5

**RAM:** 8GB

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit

**Age:** 3 to 4 years

---

**The problem:**

Upon start-up my computer makes 5 short beeps, waits, then gives me a normal bios beep before starting.

Yesterday it was giving me just a normal bios beep prior to an automatic update that Windows installed.

The day before it was giving me 5 short beeps until I got all of the drivers for my graphics card properly installed.

---

**What's been done:**

I've moved the ram into the primary slots (I had been running them both in the secondary slots since I had taken 2 out a year ago to use in another pc)

I've checked web sites, but all I can find is 5 short beeps meaning that it could be a process error... or that the bios battery could be going bad. However, it's not telling me what my specific beep code is since I am getting a normal bios beep after the 5 short beeps.

---

What could be the problem?

Comment: You should solve the cause of the 5 short beeps before you worry about the single bios beep.

Comment: It sounds like you may have a problem with your CMOS battery.  Try re-seating it and see if that helps.  (Bear in mind, this may restore your BIOS settings to default)

Comment: Per the marketing info on your mobo, it appears that you can contact ASRock Support directly from within your EFI firmware. Perhaps they will be in a better position to help you.

Comment: It seems to have gone away on its own.